# Python, namespace vs module with underscores

Tags: python, modules, packages, namespace

I'm developing a project that uses several independent modules, but all related to the same project.

However, I face this choice: module names with underscore vs. namespaces.

For example there is this tree:

```
Foo
 |-Bar1
 |  |-Bar2
 |-Foo1
 |  |-Foo2
 |  |-Foo3
```

Let's say for example, that Foo3 depends on Bar2, but Foo2 and Bar2 are standalone.

What are the best practices regarding performance, and ease to package (to pypi) and code readability:

using `_` : `Foo_Bar_Bar1`, `Foo_Foo1_Foo2` and `Foo_Foo1_Foo3`

or using namespaces: `Foo.Bar.Bar1`, `Foo.Foo1.Foo2` and `Foo.Foo1.Foo3`

It is more beautiful to use module and namespace, but on pip, independent packages are saved in different location. I've also read there is a bug when combining package installed from pypi and editable package that uses the same namespace

see also : https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3

Also, another problem about namespace is that Foo can't have any content and can't be a package (a namespace module must contain only a namespace declaration) like read here : https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#namespace-packages
(Or I didn't understand)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *but on pypi, independent packages are saved in different location.*. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: sorry, I meant pip : when you install two packages (that use namespace modules, they are installed in a different location rather than in subdirectories like when you developp a single big package

Comment: So? That doesn't make a difference to how you import them.

Comment: So you identified several very *specific* issues that limit how you can use namespaces. I never ran into the pip issue (I never install packages as editable with `pip` as I use buildout for that usecase). Don't use a shared namespace in that case, you are not forced to. That has little to do with performance however.

Answer (score 4):

I'd not be concerned about performance here, but about *usability*.

Modules are loaded just once in a Python program's lifetime. Referencing elements within modules and packages, including nested modules, is virtually free. *Performance doesn't matter here*.

Use modules to group your project into logical units; it is more readable and maintainable if things that are closely related conceptually are clustered within a namespace.